# Javascript CORS upload always finishing with an error event

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, cors

I need to upload a file to a server following the `CORS` specification with `javascript`.

There are plenty examples on the internet and in fact everything works fine (the file is uploaded) but the last fired event is an error.

If I look at the target, the `XMLHttpRequest` finsihed with a `readyState=4`. This according to the specification is

```
DONE: The data transfer has been completed or something went wrong during the transfer (e.g. infinite redirects).

source http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#dom-xmlhttprequest-readystate
```

The `status` is always `0` but the file do gets uploaded, the progress works fine and the server returns a `201 CREATED`.

A piece of code:

```
var fd = new FormData(document.getElementById('viForm'));
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false);
xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);
xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);
xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false);
xhr.open("POST", submitAddress);
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Auth-Token', token);
xhr.send(fd);


function uploadFailed(e) { console.log(e); }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that although I set the server to send back the appropriate headers in the `OPTIONS` request, I was not sending the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the actual `POST`.

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

Comment: That seems very odd to me because as far as I know, the server is the one in charge of returning this "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header. I think you actually changed something else on the server side